# What is $field in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jira, jquery-1.7

I am looking at some javascript that uses jQuery and see things like this

```
this.dropdownController.setWidth(this.$field.innerWidth());
```

But I am not sure whether `$field` is something special or just a custom-defined object somewhere in the scripts.

Does `$field` have a special meaning?

Comment: [It looks like a variable in Drupal.](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.crud.inc/function/field_update_field/7)

Comment: @Oberon Why not add this as an answer?

Comment: that's not jQuery. jQuery might be involved in it, but it's not something done by jQuery.

Comment: @RyanHenderson It's not really an answer, it's a link that was the first result in Google.

Comment: @Oberon. Understood. But from SO's perspective, that's a potential answer to question. If the OP realizes it, this question will forever appear to be "unanswered", what that's not the truth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$field` is nothing more than a property defined on `this`. It has nothing to do with jQuery. If it's something special, it's going to be related to whatever `this` is.

Comment: Ah, I thought the `$` meant something special but I guess there is no restriction that property names can't begin with a `$` in javascript.

Comment: Sometimes, you may see something like `$example = $('#xyz input.example');` as a shorthand. The `$` at the beginning is merely suggestive of the actual usage.